# xcode 9 localization App Problems

Tags: ios, iphone, localization

I'm trying to localize my app in Italian, English and Japanese language. but I've a problem. when try the localisation in iOS device to other language, the language don't change. It changes if the region be changed. E.g. The default language is English and the region of my iPhone is Italia. and if I change the language of device in Italian, app too change and become Italian. but if I change the language in Japanese or other language, like French, the language of app, don't change. remain Italian. now if I change the region to Japan, the language, change and become Japanese! just question: why?

and how can I make change the language of my app changing only the language of device?

thanks

p.s. this is the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

**UPDATE**
I don't know why, but if I try my app in the simulator, this problem don't happen. It happen only on my physical device. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution Found!!!!**

I've found the problem. I don't know why, but it solves all problem (or it seems so)

[image]

In Info.plist file I've changed Localisation native development region to Italy, as you can see in screenshot. When I restored the original value (Unite States), everything work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do your localization folder names contain a country as well as the language?  You should have `it.lproj/Localizable.strings`, not `it_IT.lproj/Localizable.strings`, for the Italian language in any region, for example.

Comment: contain only the language. then the folder's name is: it.lproj/

Comment: This is for Lou Franco

Comment: Are you saying that your folder is named `it.lproj`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, then.  I would delete the localization and re-add it back more carefully.

Comment: I have some plist that defines structure of some table. I click on one plist to select it and press the localize button. I create the file to base.lproj like base language; after that, click ok English button to create the en.lproj file. after that I go in project and add the Italian localisation and localise the Italian file. that's it! maybe I making mistake. can you give me a reliable and clear tutorial. or can you give me how do it? Thank you very much

Comment: What language is your apps default?  That one should be Base and you shouldn't repeat it.  If english is default, you don't need en.lproj (use Base for English)

Comment: You also need to add localization in the project file. Go to the Project file, Info Tab -- Add the language to the Localization section. If that looks right, put a screen shot of that screen into your question

Comment: I've added the screenshot. I've follow you instruction and now the app don't come in Italian language. because I want that the default be English, now appear only English. it seems that take the file only from Base.lproj folder

Comment: It says "1 file localized" in Italian. You need to go the the 2 files that aren't and add the localization

Comment: well, it mean that I need to localize also storyboard?

Comment: Storyboards could have strings in them -- so, if you do, then yes (like UILabel text)